# Can't migrate in Laravel4 using ClosureTable

Tags: php, laravel, transitive-closure-table

I'm using ClosureTable for Laravel. and i am having a problem with migrating.

This is what my migration script looks like:

//Page_Closure migration script

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('page_closure', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        Schema::create('page_closure', function(Blueprint $t)
        {
            $t->increments('ctid');

            $t->integer('ancestor', false, true);
            $t->integer('descendant', false, true);
            $t->integer('depth', false, true);
              //problem after this line.
            $t->foreign('ancestor')->references('id')->on('pages');
            $t->foreign('descendant')->references('id')->on('pages');
        });
    });
}
```

An error occurs when the foreign key is created. IDK why, but based on my my migration queue "page closure" runs first before the "page" script.

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                              
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'page_closure' already exists (SQL: create table `page_closure` (`ctid` int unsign  
  ed not null auto_increment primary key, `ancestor` int unsigned not null, `descendant` int unsigned not null, `depth` int unsigned not null) defa  
  ult character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `Schema::table('page_closure', ...)` then `Schema::create('page_closure', ...)` inside it. You are basically telling Laravel to find an existing table called page_closure, then create a table with the same name. That's why you are getting "Table 'page_closure' already exists" error.

You don't need the `Schema::table()` part. Just put your `$table->engine = 'InnoDB'` in your `Schema::create()` like this...

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('page_closure', function(Blueprint $t)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $t->increments('ctid');
        // ... the rest of the columns
    }
}
```

It seems like your table has already been created too but the migration was not completed. So your migration table is probably corrupt. You will need to drop the table manually and run the migration again.

Comment: Hi Unnawut, this migration script was generated after scaffolding. "php artisan closuretable:make --entity=page"  I used this package https://github.com/franzose/ClosureTable.   So there must be something wrong with the scaffold to generate a migration script with this error.

Comment: @olleh I think you might want to report a bug to them then. It doesn't look right to me having `Schema::table()` and `Schema::create()` of the same table name inside one another. I think what goes in the `Schema::table()` should be the name of your entity table, not the closure table. Maybe you can try changing that.